# Removing numbers but keeping braces in string

Tags: c#

I have a few strings which look like e.g.

```
15 Hour(s)
10 Day(s)
5 Month(s)
2 Year(s)
```

The `int` in the above strings can change depending on the user input. What I am trying to achieve is for my final string to be like

```
Hour(s)
Day(s)
...
```

For that I have created an extension method as follows:

```
public static string ExractLetter(this string original)
{
   return new string(original.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
}
```

Which works fine but it removes the `()` from the string too. So my question is how do I just remove the number and keep the `()`

Comment: You could just add that logic `c => char.IsLetter(c) || c == '(' || c == ')')`

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace("original", @"^[0-9]+\s+", "");`

Comment: Wow, so many answers in such short time with all possiblities

Comment: Here's another one `return original.Substring(original.IndexOf(' ') + 1);` Note you might want to check if `IndexOf` returns -1 if you can have values without spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If your string format are always like `15 Hour(s)` then you can `Split()` by space and take the second element like

```
"15 Hour(s)".Split(' ')[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should skip all characters that are a digit or number by using

```
return new string(original.Where(c => !char.IsDigit(c) && !char.IsNumber(c)).ToArray()).Trim();
```

Comment: This still leaves the space.

Comment: You were right. I like this approach best because it give you all the control over what gets removed

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple Regex that removes digits and spaces.

```
var input = new Array { "15 Hour(s)", "10 Day(s)", "5 Month(s)", "2 Year(s)"};
var regex = new Regex(@"[\d\s]");

foreach (var str in input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str, string.Empty));
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hour(s)
Day(s)
Month(s)
Year(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option would be to just skip until the first letter is encountered:

```
public static string ExractLetter(this string original)
{
   return new string(original.SkipWhile(!char.IsLetter).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  public static string ExractLetter(this string original)
    {
       return new string(original.Where(d => !char.IsDigit(d)).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error message `'!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'`

Comment: @Code It should be `d => !char.IsDigit(d)`

Comment: Thanks for this, I will accept it as soon as the time limit is up

Comment: @Code, note that this will keep the space as well.

Comment: @juharr I've just realised that myself

Comment: @Code You could just add a `&& d != ' '` to fix that.

Comment: @juharr I've used `Trim()`

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expression for that

```
public static string ExractLetter(this string original)
{
   return Regex.Replace(original, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I think you want `@"^\d+ "` to remove one or more digits at the begging of the line and a following space.  I doubt there's a need to handle negative numbers here.